# Curve depth not scaling uniformly

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a bunch of curves that I'm trying to thicken uniformly but when I do that, they get thinner in some places and wider in others. How can I increase the thickness evenly?

[image: Curves before increasing depth]

[image: Curves with uneven thickness]

Comment: Have you tried to apply the scale and transforms to check it persists?

Comment: Also.. (depending on your method) perhaps ensure your curves, (path and profile) are set to '2D' in their Data tab > Shape panel